# i am trying to upload image in django but it gives me MultiValueDictKeyError at /index 'myfile'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I tried to insert image into sqlite but it didn't worked with it gives me error evertime
this is my code

```
def index(request):
    dbname = 'user1'
    cursor = connections[dbname].cursor()
    if request.POST.get('done'):
        cursor.execute('insert into images values(%s)', [request.FILES['myfile']])
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

and this is the error

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /index
'myfile'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/index
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'myfile'
Exception Location: D:\omar\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py, line 78, in __getitem__
Python Executable:  D:\omar\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.2
Python Path:    
['D:\\omar\\pythonProject',
 'C:\\Users\\taha_lab\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\taha_lab\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\taha_lab\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\taha_lab\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'D:\\omar\\pythonProject\\venv',
 'D:\\omar\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 28 Jun 2021 00:18:52 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
D:\omar\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py, line 76, in __getitem__
            list_ = super().__getitem__(key) …
▶ Local vars
During handling of the above exception ('myfile'), another exception occurred:
D:\omar\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
D:\omar\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
D:\omar\pythonProject\Dhb\views.py, line 5951, in index
        cursor.execute('insert into images values(%s)', [request.FILES['myfile']]) …
▶ Local vars
D:\omar\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py, line 78, in __getitem__
            raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
```

I tried to insert image into sqlite but it didn't worked with it gives me error evertime

Answer (score 0):

Django has ORM for a reason, use imagefield or filefield https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/
Storages can also be used.